# How Would I Isolate for $b$ in $t=\frac{\ln(b/a)}{(b-a)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation for the time at which the concentration of an intermediate species in a series reaction reaches a maximum and its in terms of the constants $a$ and $b$, and I'd just like to know how one would isolate for $b$.

Comment: Lambert W function

Comment: Can you show the solution

Answer (score 4):

I will try to show you how it is done with the Lambert $W$ function.
Let us first rewrite the equation as:

$$
e^t = \frac{\frac{b}{a}}{e^{b}e^{-a}}
$$
Then multiplying by $a$ and $e^{-a}$ gives us
$$
\frac{ae^t}{e^a} = be^{-b}
$$
Now we substitute x = -b, so
$$
-\frac{ae^t}{e^a} = xe^{x}
$$
Notice that that I changed signs. Now we can use the W function to find X. So $ x = W(-{ae^t}/{e^a})$ and therefore we can see that our final answer is
$$
b = -W\left(-\frac{ae^t}{e^a}\right)
$$

See Wikipedia for the Lambert $W$ function, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can write:

$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right)}{\text{b}-\text{a}}=\ln\left(\left(\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{b}-\text{a}}\right)\tag1$$

When $\text{a}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\text{b}\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$

Taking the $\exp$ of both sides:

$$\exp\left(t\right)=\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{b}-\text{a}}\right)\right)=\left(\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{b}-\text{a}}\tag2$$

Take both sides to the power $\text{b}-\text{a}$:

$$\left(\exp\left(t\right)\right)^{\text{b}-\text{a}}=\exp\left(t\cdot\left(\text{b}-\text{a}\right)\right)=\left(\left(\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{b}-\text{a}}\right)^{\text{b}-\text{a}}=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\tag3$$

Now, we can write:

$$\exp\left(t\cdot\left(\text{b}-\text{a}\right)\right)=\exp\left(t\cdot\text{b}-t\cdot\text{a}\right)=\exp\left(t\cdot\text{b}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-t\cdot\text{a}\right)\tag4$$

So:

$$\exp\left(t\cdot\text{b}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-t\cdot\text{a}\right)=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\text{a}}{\exp\left(t\cdot\text{a}\right)}=\frac{\text{b}}{\exp\left(t\cdot\text{b}\right)}\tag5$$