Solving $\frac{\ln(y/x)}{y-x} = t$ for $x$
I am having trouble solving an algebra formula which is for a project of mine.
I must solve for $x$ ($y$ is a known value).
$$\frac{\ln\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}{y-x} = t$$
As I try to solve the formula, my first step is:
$$\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = t (y-x) $$
or
$$ (y-x) = \frac{\ln\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}{t}$$
This is causing me to get stuck on trying to solve the rest, I don't know how I would go about doing this because the unknown value, $x$, is on both sides.

Think about Lambert function.

From
$$
\ln(\frac{y}{x}) = ty - tx
$$
you would get
$$
\frac{y}{x} = \exp(ty-tx)
$$
or
$$
\frac{x}{y} = \exp(tx - ty) = \frac{ \exp tx}{\exp ty}
$$
from which
$$
\frac{x}{\exp tx} = \frac{y}{\exp ty}
$$

A numerical solution is imminent. For almost all values $y>0$, there are two values for $x$ that are solutions (if there even is a solution ... The maximum occurs at $x=1/t$.)

Does this answer your question? How Would I Isolate for $b$ in $t=\frac{\ln(b/a)}{(b-a)}$? – found with Approach0

@MartinR Could you please check the answer to this question about isolating $b$? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2499718/654465 Is it correct? I think he has rewritten the equation incorrectly.

To the OP: I suggest you search your question on Approach0 before posting so as to avoid duplicate posts. Regards.

The equation is an irreducible polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($\ln(\frac{y}{x}),x$). We therefore don't know how to solve the equation by rearranging by applying finite numbers of only elementary functions we can read from the equation.

We can express $x$ in terms of $y$ and $t$ using the Lambert W-function or product log function.
We have,
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac yx\right)}{y-x}=t\implies \ln y-\ln x=ty-tx\implies \ln y-ty+\ln t=\ln(tx)-tx=\ln\left(txe^{-tx}\right)$$
i.e.
$$\ln\left(tye^{-ty}\right)=\ln\left(txe^{-tx}\right)\implies -tye^{-ty}=-txe^{-tx}\implies-tx=W\left(-tye^{-ty}\right)$$
i.e.
$$\color{blue}{x=-\frac{W\left(-tye^{-ty}\right)}{t}}$$
where $W(z)$ is the Lambert W-function.

It is a duplicate.

@MartinR Oh, yes! I just saw the question is similar to that. Thanks!
